# JAVA .wait() for waiting before runing a method android studio

Tags: java, android, wait, thread-sleep

So, I am working in android studio and trying to set a pause between two methods. In the first one, a gif is loaded and in the second one a pop-up message appears. I've tried to use Thread.sleep and the TimeUnit as bellow but both of them execute in a way that the time is waited before running everything else. In another words, my code down bellow waits 4 seconds and then runs gameGif() and gameFinish() simultaneously. Here is my piece of code:

```
        gameGif();
        {
            try
            {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {}
        }

        gameFinish();
```

Comment: The value you are passing is to small because its in milli seconds if you want it to stop for 4 sec pass 4000 in argument

Comment: It probably doesn't behave as you describe, but your sleep hogs the CPU so that nothing can run in this thread. Surely Android has the equivalent of `java.awt.image.ImageObserver`?

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me

```
gameGif();

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        gameFinish();
    }
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is setting the intention to update the UI. The actual UI updates are performed by the Android Looper separate to your code. In fact, by calling `wait()`, you're actually blocking the rendering thread from doing its update.

Using a `Handler` is the correct way to do it, as Matus posts. The `Handler` will organise the scheduling with the `Looper` and will still allow the Looper to run (i.e. is non-blocking). When the timeout elapses it will call the `Runnable`

The one thing you need to be careful with this approach, is to call the Handler on the UI loop (i.e. from one of the 'normal' Android methods). If you call it from your own `Thread` it won't interact with the Looper correctly.